# Set reverse security-constraint

Tags: java, security, jsp

I am trying to set up security-constraints backwards.  I want to say all pages need a login except for the ones I specify.  I use:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

But I can't figure out how to say index.jsp doesn't need a login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that you cannot achieve this using web.xml (arguably a good thing, since security mechanisms are best kept as simple as possible). As @Johan says, secure some url pattern such as `/secure/*` or `/app/*` and put all your pages there.

Answer (score 0):

Either put all secure pages `/secure` and configure your security filter to `/secure/*`, or  create an exclusion in your filtering config. The following sample is based on spring-security:

```
<http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp*" filters="none"/>
</http>
```

Comment: Although this is 100% correct, the OP was asking about the web.xml deployment descriptor, and didn't indicate that they are using spring-security. Since the web.xml constraints are enforced at the container level, these two approaches can't readily be mixed, either.